# Grouping timestamps together by interval and counting the difference in seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

I’ve got a logging table that logs various data. Sometimes multiple rows are created per timestamp and sometimes it can be a few seconds before more log entries hit the table. What I’d like to do is group records together that fall within, say, 2-3 minutes of each other and count the difference in seconds of those two entries. And, if possible, choose the most popular “category”.

I’m really unsure about how to go about this but say my data is like so:

```
datetime                message                        category
2019-04-03 12:30:00     etc/bar/x did something        b
2019-04-03 12:30:00     there was a failure            b
2019-04-03 12:30:01     xyz is corrupt                 a
2019-04-03 12:31:00     something different            a
2019-04-03 12:31:00     drive on mnt/x is full         c
2019-04-03 12:31:00     extra info                     b
2019-04-03 12:31:05     /etc/bar/foo did something     c
2019-04-03 12:40:01     foo output x                   a
2019-04-03 12:41:30     another message                a
```

What I’d like to get is:

```
Total time     category
00:01:05       b         # Note this is 1 min, 5 secs, not 1:05am!
00:01:29       a         # Note this is 1 min 29 secs, not 1:29am!
```

Where the first col is hh:mm:ss (not timestamp but a count of the time, so 1 min 5 secs). Any ideas on how to attack this?

Or, alternatively, I’m glad to just get the low and high time output such:

```
Time between              avg category
2019-04-03 12:30:00       b                      # Note this is the start timestamp, 12:30:00pm
2019-04-03 12:31:05       c                      # Note this is the end timestamp, 12:31:05pm
2019-04-03 12:40:01       a
2019-04-03 12:41:30       a
```

Comment: Why `Total time` isn't 1 min on `b` column because the max time is `12:31:00` in your sample data

Comment: What is the data type for the column "Timestamp"? is it Time HH:mm:ss?

Comment: So, its group by `category` where `MAX(time) - MIN(time)` for each category, correct?

Comment: @D-Shih the 12:31:00 in this case is the actual clock time. 31 minutes, zero seconds past 12 mid day. The count I’m happy with hours (0-999999) minutes (0-59) and seconds (0-59)

Comment: @tcadidot0: not necessarily. The category I'm not overly fussed by - it's just a nice to have but it's the time when stuff falls close to each other that's the important factor

Answer (score 1):

For the first output, you could try this query:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(MAX(timestamp))-TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(timestamp))) AS "Total Time",
Category FROM your_table GROUP BY category;
```

Whereby `TIME_TO_SEC` converting your `TIME` value into total seconds. So `MAX(timestamp)` minus `MIN(timestamp)` value for each category (both were converted into seconds value). Then, the result of that is converted back to time by using `SEC_TO_TIME` operation. Therefore, you'll get the `Total Time` in hh:mm:ss format.

For the second output, you could try this query:

```
SELECT MIN(timestamp) AS "Timestamp",category 
FROM your_table GROUP BY category UNION 
SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS "Timestamp",category 
FROM your_table GROUP BY category ORDER BY category;
```

Getting `MIN(timestamp)` value on top of the union query and `MAX(timestamp)` value below. Finished with `ORDER BY category`.

IF you have `DATE` columns and you want to separate each category by date, you simply add the column in your select and group by. For example:

```
SELECT Date,
SEC_TO_TIME(TIME_TO_SEC(MAX(timestamp))-TIME_TO_SEC(MIN(timestamp))) AS "Total Time",
Category FROM your_table GROUP BY date,category;
```

AND

```
SELECT Date,MIN(timestamp) AS "Timestamp",category 
FROM your_table GROUP BY category UNION 
SELECT Date,MAX(timestamp) AS "Timestamp",category 
FROM your_table GROUP BY Date,category ORDER BY date,category;
```

**EDIT:**
Try this query below:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE category="b" 
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp),UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 180) sub1 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE category="b") sub2 
ON sub1.category=sub2.category AND DATE(sub1.timestamp)=DATE(sub2.timestamp) 
AND sub1.timestamp<>sub2.timestamp
AND sub2.timestamp BETWEEN sub1.timestamp AND sub1.timestamp + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE;
```

Comment: The first query is so close however it seems to lump things together by category over a large time range when the categories are... fluid. For example: say I had a few entries at 2019-04-03 17:01:01 --> 2019-04-03 17:04:05 and then more in the same category for 2019-04-03 18:00:00 --> 2019-04-03 18:05:05 I'd expect the output to be two rows of 00:03:01 and 00:05:05 - even though they're the same category if that makes sense?

Comment: If we group it by the hour?

Comment: By the way @ScottMcGready, your `timestamp` datatype, is it `DATETIME`?

Comment: Sorry, should have indicated - removed the dates for ease of formatting but it seems to have thrown people - apologies. Yes, it's a `datetime`

Comment: Updated question table data to reflect this.

Comment: "Session" is what come to my mind @ScottMcGready. If you are aiming to get total time by the hour, you could just add grouping by `HOUR()`. But what if in the hour, there are more than one session per category? Would you want to separate them as well?

Comment: Yes, hence why the plan is to group records that fall within 2 minutes of each other, taking the "low" (start datetime) point and "high" (end datetime) point, adding those together. This allows for records to have a 3 minute gap and grouped into another time span.

Comment: I see. I might be able to construct one query if the 3 minute gap is fixed. Let me try first